# Windows 7 Pro/Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation issues

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I wonder if someone can help me figure out why I can't set up a Windows 7 laptop for dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?
I have been trying for a couple of weeks now. The problem is seems to be that gparted doesn't recognize the partitions or partition labels correctly. I have tried

-Following the standard instructions for installation (trying to change partitions with gparted first).

-Changing the partitions with Windows in several ways (creating unallocated space, new drive, free space)
but Ubuntus installer never sees the partitions correctly.

-I have also checked how Windows is booting. It seems to be BIOS instead of UEFI. I have an HP 350 G1 with Windows 7 Pro. I want to use Windows with Android Studio and the newest Eclipse, so deleting Windows doesn't seem to be an option.

I don't blame Ubuntu. I even tried installing freeBSD and netBSD with the same result. It looks more like Windows is to blame or rather maybe that some Windows 7 computers have technology (EFI motherboard?) that is meant for Windows 8 and that this confuses disk partitioners.
Maybe the problem will dissappear after Windows 9 comes out???

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Happy Holiday season to all!

Hello gyropyge! Thank you! I will take another look at the partitions. I seem to recall a very small partition just as you said. Not exactly sure how to copy contents of the little partition, but I will look into it and give it a try.

Comment: Did you turn off the Windows dynamic partitioning and fast boot (a power option)?  Those could cause the problem.

Comment: Hello ubfan1, I looked into the matter but I don't want to delete everything as the help file says needs to be done to change to a standard disk. I don't even have a DVD disk on hand to backup, but thank you for the advice anyway!

Comment: You need to post these from Ubuntu live installer's terminal: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo fdisk -lu` If drive is gpt then the fdisk will not tell much. Just to be clear the MBR(msdos) limit on primary partitions is 4, but one primary can be made an extended partition and hold an unlimited number of logical partitions. With gpt the soft limit is  128, but users can change that.

Comment: Thanks Fred! I'll try that. I just need to get some sleep first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I know what the problem is, and I can tell you how to fix this without deleting or reinstalling Windows.  I've run into this problem twice and fixed it both times with this method.

You see, prior to EFI/UEFI, there was a grandfathered-in limit of how many partitions any drive was permitted to have.  I seem to recall the limit is three, or is it two... maybe it is four?  In any case, if you want to have more than x-number of partitions, the "trick" involves making one or more "virtual" partitions within an "extended" partition.  It's been this way since the early 90's or there abouts.  It was always awkward and kludgey, but we accepted and worked with it because that was what we had to do.

It appears that Microsoft finally realized they could beat out us LINUX geeks and gain a semi-monopoly of the PCs upon which Windows was installed if all they did was fill the hard drives with primary partitions, so that novices to the artificial limitation would be unable to partition the drive further, but there's a way around this which I will now explain.

If you boot your drive with external boot media, such as an Ubuntu Live CD, you can manipulate all of the partitions.  One of the partitions will be quite small, perhaps only a gb and be formatted in something weird like MS-DOS.  If you copy the contents of that partition into a new folder under one of the larger partitions (give it a name like "moved from msdos partition"), that frees up an entire partition slot.

After deleting the tiny partition, use gparted to slide all the remaining partitions neatly to the left and create an "extended" partition to the right.  But you don't really have to do that because once there's room your ubuntu installer will take care of the rest.  This partition juggling thing is the only thing Ubuntu cannot do for itself.

Something else that I do, which you don't really need to do, is that I usually resize partitions while I'm at it to give the new Linux partitions not less than 80gb, personally and divide it into two partitions, one being a 4gb swap partition.  All these things are usually done automatically by Ubuntu to one degree or another.  I've simply been at this long enough (as I can see you have been as well.

Your final partitioning scheme could very well look EXACTLY like [this image](http://linuxgeekoid.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/linuxgeekoid_partitionproj_logical_extended_primary.png) I found online.

Comment: Hello gyropyge! Thank you! I will take another look at the partitions. I seem to recall a very small partition just as you said. Not exactly sure how to copy contents of the little partition, but I will look into it and give it a try.

Comment: @David , when I used the word "exactly" I only kind of meant exactly.  I meant that the numbers would seem out of sequence, but you could tell by the indentation which ones were formed under the extended partition and based upon that you could also tell that the reason you were permitted to create them was the presence of the extended partition.  The screenshot I found online also answers questions for you such as whether all the partitions need to be formatted the same way, which as you can see, they do not.

Comment: Hello again! I remember using that sort of technique several years ago on another computer so I marked the answer as helpful, thank you! The last time I deleted a partition, I deleted HP_Tools. This time, for some reason, I deleted Recovery. Not good. Something went wrong during installation, and now Windows won't boot up. I've tried a lot the past few days. Need to get some sleep and try again tommorrow.

Comment: @David HP_Tools sounds much more like they tiny partition I was referring to, even though I'm fairly certain the last such laptop I juggled the partitions on was actually a Dell.

Comment: I should have tried deleting the Tools partition this time. The only thing I was worried about was BIOS updating, but I learned too late that can be done with bootable media. Happy New Year!

Comment: @David, that's why my advice specifically mentioned COPYING the files out of that partition so that they would not be deleted.  Actually as far as bios updating is concerned, it's all available online anyway.

Comment: I should have copied the files, I just couldn't find an empty disk. But, Ubuntu is running so well now that I am starting to feel like leaving things the way they are for a while. The Ubuntu community has been a great help!

Comment: @David, I too prefer to live by the old saying, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."  In this case, I prefer to think Windows was built broken anyway, so even if you were to fix the booting issue you still have the terminal Windows problem.  If you follow my comments here you'll find a recurring thread that it seems at least that dual boots often seem to end with boot sector viruses which simply don't seem to happen when windows isn't on the drive.  So, don't think of this so much as laziness but practicality.

Comment: It has taken a while, but I have gotten so many answers here that Ubuntu feels more and more like a natural operating environment for me... especially after figuring out how to get my most used programs up and running. I even found a way to play Windows media files today. Then there is a place that sells Ubuntu computers online, system76.... definitely on my wishlist. :)

Comment: @David, DELL sells Ubuntu computers, as do many major manufacturers.  Not surprisingly, their price with Ubuntu pre-installed is IDENTICAL to the price with NO OS installed.  I hadn't realized you were so new you were unclear about opening media files.  You can actually open MORE formats of media files with Ubuntu than with Windows (and without spending money on fancy players).  If you like we can pick this up in chat and I'll give you a simple tutorial on configuring WINE to seamlessly run most windows software under Ubuntu.

Comment: That sounds great, thanks! Just let me know a time and day. I am in Europe GMT +1. My Internet usage is over the limit for December, so I must wait until after midnight tonight to have functional Internet again. Happy New Year!

Comment: @David strangely I didn't see your response until just now.  I'll give you a quick rundown of how to make WINE work without grief, and if you are still in need of direction we can discuss it.  Step1: DO NOT INSTALL WINE.  Step2: go to the software center and install "winetricks".  It will take a long time, roughly identical to installing STEAM.  After winetricks is installed open it which will cause it to do yet more updates.  After all that also install "play on linux".  Between both there will be very little in the way of Windows software and games you cannot install.  Word, MSIE, etc.

Comment: Thanks gyropyge! I\ll try that. I could not find winetricks on the software center, but when I have more time, I will look around some more. That would be amazing if I could use my old Windows software that I cannot use on Windows anymore haha. :)